# Winamp sync between Windows 7 and Android not working

Tags: windows-7, sync, android, winamp

I've installed Winamp both on my Android phone (Sony EriCSSon Xperia X10 Mini Pro) and on my computer (running Windows 7) and successfully managed to pair the two. However, the music library on my phone is entirely empty when browsing it from my computer (as in step 10 in [this guide](http://blog.winamp.com/2010/11/30/wirelessly-sync-music-to-your-Android-phone/)).

Winamp on the phone can find all the files, and there are files on the computer that don't exist on the phone (but not the opposite, I believe...). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Media Library in Winamp is gray (no files)](http://bugitory.com/index.php?title=Media_Library_in_Winamp_is_gray_%28no_files%29), you could try (I suggest starting with the 2nd solution) :

> **Solution 1. Remove main.idx**
>
> Most likely the main.idx database file
>   has become corrupted. Delete it and
>   you'll be able to re-add music folders
>   to the Media Library.
>
> 1. Via Start -> Run (XP) or Start -> Search box (Vista/7), run
>      %appdata%\winamp\plugins\ml.
> 2. Delete main.idx.
> 3. Restart Winamp.
> 4. Import music folders to library.
>
> **Solution 2. Run as administrator**
>
> 1. Right-click on the shortcut you use to start Winamp.
> 2. Click Properties.
> 3. Click Advanced....
> 4. Check Run as administrator.

Comment: Your link is broken (due to a server error on their side, it seems...), but I will try this next time I start Windows.

Comment: I got the above content thru the google cache, and my quote contains all of the relevant text.

Comment: I've now tested this, and unfortunately it doesn't work at all... =( I saw no change in behavior after following either of the two fix suggestions.

Comment: Can you try : disabling UAC, reboot, and try again?

Comment: And are you using the latest Winamp versions ?

Comment: I'm using Winamp 5.61 on the PC, and 1.0.3 on the phone. I doubt UAC is the problem, since running the program as admin didn't help (and the problem seems to be more related to reading the phone's music library from the PC than to the PC's own music library...).

Comment: Have you verified what you did against [Winamp for Android - Media Sync](http://help.aol.com/help/microsites/microsite.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&externalId=47410&sliceId=1&docTypeID=DT_AOLHOW_TO_1_1) ?

Comment: Yup, done all that.

Comment: Then what is happening to you is completely abnormal, and the solution may require specialized knowledge. I suggest to post the question in the [Winamp Forums](http://forums.winamp.com/) with the details of your versions and what you did and even a screenshot of the problem.

Comment: I've stopped using Winamp (most of what I listen to is streamed now anyway...) but in case someone else with similar problems comes across this, your solution will probably work.